# create multidiamensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array(
[question]
       [0]=>fggg
       [1]=>gggg
[question_type]
        [0]=>1
         [1]=>2
[opt]
    [0]=>hh
    [1]=>kk

)
```

And I need it as

```
Array(
[0]=>
    [question]
        [0]=>fggg
    [question_type]
        [0]=>1
     [opt]
       [0]=>hh
[1]=>
    [question]
        [0]=>gggg
    [question_type]
        [0]=>2
     [opt]
       [0]=>kk
)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't have an array with duplicate keys.

Comment: Show php code which you have done so far

Comment: $array[] = your array..

Comment: do you want to get values from 'question' column only?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little information you provided, this should work for you.

```
<?php foreach($input as $key => $value){
         foreach($value as $k => $val){
            $output[$k][$key][] = $val;
         }
}
?>
```